# How to trigger a jQuery function from code-behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to call a jQuery function from ASP.NET code behind.

I don't want it to be triggered by the jQuery click event; I want to trigger the jQuery function--->"show the dialog" in the code behind of my control.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LinkButton1").click(function(){
        $("#hightlight_show1").toggle();
    });

    var dialog1 = $("#Add").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 620,
            height: 400
    });

    // Move the dialog back into the <form> element 
    dialog1.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

    $("#BT_add").click(function () {
       $("#Add").dialog("open");
       return false;
});
```

I have tried something like this but it did not work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#LinkButton1").click(function () {
        $("#hightlight_show1").toggle();
    });

    var dialog1 = $("#Add").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 620,
        height: 400
    });

    // Move the dialog back into the <form> element 
    dialog1.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

    function a() {
        $("#Add").dialog("open");
        return false;
    };

});
```

I specify this in the code behind using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript()`:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
    this.GetType(),
    "a",
    "a();",
    true
 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, move your `function a() {` out of the `$(document).ready()`.

But you might still have an issue with order of execution.

If this is a full postback, then wrap the `a()` call in your `RegisterStartupScript` with another `$(document).ready()`. If it's a partial postback from an `UpdatePanel`, it should work as long as the dialog was properly created the first time the page loaded.

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Check your browser's javascript console.

Comment: I have used different way to get around it, too much time spend on jquery. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You **can not trigger JavaScript function from code behind**. You can define JavaScript function on html page and bind the click event on server side using Control.Attributes.Add. You will need server control to bind the event, you can make html control server accessible by put runat="server"

*Javascript*

```
function  YourFun(){
    $("#hightlight_show1").toggle();
}
```

*Code behind*

```
hightlight_show1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "YourFun();");
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it would be difficult for a server-side (c#) action to affect a client-side (jQuery) event. You would need to use ajax to request information from the server that would launch the event.

Remember, c# / ASP code runs on a web-server and it's job is just to send HTML to a browser upon request. After that, its role is essentially complete. JavaScript and jQuery and the like are interpreted by the *browser*, but only long after the document has already left the server. There are ""ways"" you can get c# to trigger a jQuery event in a very loose sense, but ultimately you'd still have to recognize the division between client (browser) and web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaring `function a()` within the `document.ready` function.

The Register.StartupScript will add the code to document.onload, are your sure which event is firing (ready or onload)?.

Declare it outside of document.ready and it will probably work. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript>

function a() {
    $("#Add").dialog("open");
    return false;
};

$(document).ready(function () {
     $("#LinkButton1").click(function(){
         $("#hightlight_show1").toggle();
     });

     // Move the dialog back into the <form> element 
     dialog1.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));

     var dialog1 = $("#Add").dialog({
         autoOpen: false,
         width: 620,
         height: 400
     });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is actually you problem, but in the "code you tried" you're missing the closing double quotes (") on your script tag declaration.

You wrote: `type="text/javascript`

but never closed the declaration... That would definitely mess things up for otherwise working JS.

Answer (score 0):

Do this

**MarkUp**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ShowPopup(message) {
        $(function () {
            $("#dialog").html(message);
            $("#dialog").dialog({
                title: "jQuery Dialog Popup",
                buttons: {
                    Close: function () {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    }
                },
                modal: true
            });
        });
    };
</script>
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnShowPopup" runat="server" Text="Show Popup" OnClick="btnShowPopup_Click" />
```

**Code behind**

```
  protected void btnShowPopup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string message = "Message from server side";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Popup", "ShowPopup('" + message + "');", true);
}
```

Download Working demo [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81286708/testweb.zip) in C# and VB

Comment: this probably is the good solution, but it did not work for my case, maybe i messed this up in somewhere else.

Comment: Which version of J -query libraries are you using.And if your stuff is in an  update panel ,then you need to initialize the dialog again in the end request function.